# Where should I define my resque logger in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I have set up Resque in my rails application and it's all working fine.  The  question I have is where should the logger setup go.  Should it be in the initializer or in the rake task?  It works when set up in both.  The reason I ask is I have seen it used in both in examples across the net.

I am thinking that it should probably be in the initializer as it's best practice to put setup into initializers.

*config/initializers/resque.rb*

```
logfile = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'resque.log'), 'a')
logfile.sync = true
Resque.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(logfile)
Resque.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

I am then writing out using the Resque.logger syntax in the rake task and jobs.

E.G:

```
Resque.logger.info "Resque task started!"
```

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I'll stick with the initializer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely put it inside initializer, since it needs to be called only once, while setting up your server.

Answer (score 0):

Another choice: config the resque logger inside every job if config it in initializer(`config/initializers/resquer.rb`) or rake (`lib/tasks/resque.rake`) neither work for you, it is not perfect but just works.

```
class OneJob
  def self.perform
    Resque.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/resque.log")
    Resque.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG   

    Resque.logger.info 'Job starts'
    ...
  end
en
```